# Strange error initing a view in Swift

Tags: swift

I have these lines to init a view

```
let rect : CGRect = CGRectMake(0,0,320,100)
var vista : UIView = init(frame: rect)
```

but if I transpose the rect declaration to the second line like this

```
var vista : UIView = init(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,320,100))
```

it gives me this error:

[image]

why?

Comment: Seems like it should work. You should probably [submit a bug to apple](http://bugreport.apple.com). However you should probably use the prefered Swift method of creating a CGRect: `CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 100)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using initialiser incorrectly, the correct way is

```
var vista : UIView = UIView(frame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,100))
```

Comment: fantastic, thanks. I was finding that there was something wrong there!